# Alert - Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Not be able to click on 'OK' in Alert box in the last step. I also tried the control the pop up window

```
public class MyFirst {
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoAlertPresentException,InterruptedException {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\kunal.bhaskar\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");

      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      String baseUrl = "https://www.goindigo.in";

      driver.get(baseUrl);


     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input[1]")).clear();      
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input[1]")).sendKeys("Patna");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[2]/input[1]")).sendKeys("Bengaluru");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[3]/input")).click();
     Select adult = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[3]/div/div[1]/label[2]/select")));
    adult.selectByVisibleText("2");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"depart-date\"]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"depart-date\"]")).sendKeys("18 Oct 2017");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"return-date\"]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"return-date\"]")).sendKeys("28 Oct 2017");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/div/div/div/ul/li[1]/div/div[1]")).click();
    driver.switchTo().alert().accept(); 

}
```

Comment: what error do you get?

Comment: I am not able to click on 'OK' button in the last step

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoAlertPresentException is the error

Comment: No, It's still not working

Comment: Where u get the alert Please tell me I dont get the alert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, that's is not an alert. It's a modal box that's why you get the no alert present Exception.

code for modal box.

```
WebElement findElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='globalModal']/div/div/div[3]/button"));

JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", findElement);
```

write these lines in your code instead of  `driver.switchTo().alert().accept();`. 
it will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

It is not an alert dear and you rty to close it with `alert.accept()` thats why gave exception

try this

```
WebElement alertbox= driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //*[@id='globalModal']/div/div/div[3]/button"));
alertbox.click();
```

Comment: It is not an alert dear and you rty to close it with alert.accept() thats why gave exception